# Expected TensorFlowOpLayer but TFOpLambda returned

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am creating a keras model with the Functional API. However, not all the intermediate layers are of the type I expect. Specifically, this is the code:

```
def alpaca_model(image_shape=IMG_SIZE, data_augmentation=data_augmenter()):

input_shape = image_shape + (3,)

### START CODE HERE

base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=input_shape,
                                               include_top=False, # <== Important!!!!
                                               weights='imagenet') # From imageNet

# freeze the base model by making it non trainable
base_model.trainable = False 

# create the input layer (Same as the imageNetv2 input size)
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=input_shape) # create the input node of the graph

# apply data augmentation to the inputs
x = data_augmentation(inputs)# this applies Sequential API layer to the Input callable object

# data preprocessing using the same weights the model was trained on
x = preprocess_input(x)

# set training to False to avoid keeping track of statistics in the batch norm layer
x = base_model(x,training=False)

# add the new Binary classification layers
x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)  # compute the mean in each channel
# include dropout with probability of 0.2 to avoid overfitting
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2)(x)
    
# use a prediction layer with one neuron (as a binary classifier only needs one)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)(x)
    
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

return model
```

The problem is that the operation `preprocess_input(x)` and `base_model(x)` return a layer  which is of type TFOpLambda and with shape  (None, 160, 160, 3), which is a tuple, while I would expect a layer with type TensorFlowOpLayer and shape [(None, 160, 160, 3)].

Do you have any hint on what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

**TL, DR**

This issue comes running the code under different versions of TensorFlow. If you run the code through *TensorFlow 2.3.0* or earlier, this issue would disappear. If you run the latest version of TensorFlow (i.e. *TensorFlow 2.10.0* or later), those layers inside the `preprocess_input` were categorized as `TensorFlowOpLayer` will be categorized as `TFOpLambda`, which will not affect your model.

**Details**

From my experience. this issue comes from the the changes behind the `preprocess_input`. If you check those layers implemented inside `preprocess_input`, you will find out the two `TFOpLambda` represents two math manipulations (`tf.math.truediv_4(TFOpLambda)` and `tf.math.subtract_4(TFOpLambda)`).
Here is the `preprocess_input` reference [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/mobilenet_v2/preprocess_input). From the `preprocess_input` source code, we can tell that `tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.preprocess_input` implements `tf.keras.applications.imagenet_utils.preprocess_input`.

Given the `mode` in `tf.keras.applications.imagenet_utils.preprocess_input` is set as `tf`. It seems like `imagenet_utils.preprocess_input` implementing the [`_preprocess_symbolic_input`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.14.0/keras/applications/imagenet_utils.py#L251). Inside the `_preprocess_symbolic_input` source code, we can find the two math expressions being categorized as `TFOpLambda`.

```
if mode == "tf":
    x /= 127.5
    x -= 1.0
    return x
```

TensorFlow also gives the `TFOpLambda` definition (Wraps arbitrary expressions ), which match its use in `_preprocess_symbolic_input`.